# Is it possible to have one Sql-Server cluster node in multiple Sql-Server clusters?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2016, high-availability, failover

Is it possible to create FAILOVER CLUSTER A with Node01 (active) and Node02 (passive) and FAILOVER CLUSTER B with the same Node02 (passive) and Node03 (active)?

I realized that SQL Server instances on passive nodes are not charged, only the OS. So sharing a node for more than one passive Sql-Instance would make sense here. I know, once cluster A and cluster B have an issue I am nipped...

But is this an allowed and/or common scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create FAILOVER CLUSTER A with Node01 (active) and
>   Node02 (passive) and FAILOVER CLUSTER B with the same Node02 (passive)
>   and Node03 (active)?

No you cannot. This is enforced by Windows Server Failover Clustering.

> I realized that SQL Server instances on passive nodes are not charged,
>   only the OS. So sharing a node for more than one passive Sql-Instance
>   would make sense here. I know, once cluster A and cluster B have an
>   issue I am nipped...

There is nothing stopping you from creating a 3-node cluster (all nodes in the same cluster) and installing two SQL Server FCIs. You'll get roughly the same results.

Comment: Isn't SQL Server (2016) Standard Edition stopping me from creating a 3-node cluster?

Comment: Standard edition is stopping you form having 3 nodes for the *same* instance. It says nothing about having more than one instance in a cluster. If you have three nodes and an instance on N1 and N2 and another instance on N3 and N2 you're not violating anything.